# JQuery not loaded for Telerik RadCodeBlock in IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, internet-explorer-9, rad-controls

I have used $find from JQuery into a telerik RadCodeBlock, as shown bellow:

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadScriptBlock1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ScrollToSelectedNodes() {
            var treeview = $find("<%= treeViewFields.ClientID %>");
            ...
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

The function works well in all the newest browser versions (Firefox, Chrome, IE10, Safari, Safari Mobile), however it does not work in IE9 where I get a "$find is undefined " Error.

The Telerik.Web.UI assembly includes the jQuery JavaScript library and therefore I guess the RadCodeBlock control also includes JQuery library, right?.  I guess it does, but is not doing it well for IE9?.